# Is there a difference between sys.frame and parent.frame?

Tags: r

According to the documentation, `parent.frame(n)` is equivalent to `sys.frame(sys.parent(n))`. But the `which` argument can accept negative number which means to go back. So are `parent.frame(n)` and `sys.frame(-n)` equivalent?